# Melt: how to extract a frame every second?

Tags: video-editing, mlt

If I use:

```
melt -profile square_ntsc movie.flv -consumer avformat:image%05d.jpg s=60x45
```

I get so many images as many frames are in movie.

How do I extract an image each second? (the frame rate is known). Same as how do I extract an image every n-th frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer: just add a r=1 for consumer, like in:

```
melt -profile square_pal movie.flv -consumer avformat:image%05d.jpg r=1
```

to get 2 images each second, write:

```
melt -profile square_pal movie.flv -consumer avformat:image%05d.jpg r=2
```

to get images each 2 seconds, write:

```
melt -profile square_pal movie.flv -consumer avformat:image%05d.jpg r=0.5
```